# Copying array values to multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've stuck with basics of JavaScript array. here is my code

```
let arr = ['students', 'exams', [{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60},{'grade_sub1':'A', 'grade_sub2':'B'}]];
let new_arr = [];

new_arr = new_arr.concat(arr);
console.log(new_arr); //output : ['students', 'exams', [{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60},{'grade_sub1':'A', 'grade_sub2':'B'}]]

new_arr[2].pop();
let sub_arr = [];
sub_arr = sub_arr.concat(arr);

console.log(sub_arr); //output: ['students', 'exams',[{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60}]]
```

Expected output for sub_arr is `['students', 'exams', [{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60},{'grade_sub1':'A', 'grade_sub2':'B'}]]`

I've tried using `slice()` also. it didn't work. plz help me with this issue.

Comment: it's better to use JS Sets (use `new Set()`) as they are more performant. Furthermore sets only allow unique elements, and automatically delete equivalent elements.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: And for debugging JS arrays, especially with objects use `console.table(array)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is deep clone.JSON.parse and then JSON.stringify instead will do the job for this.

```js
let arr = ['students', 'exams', [{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60},{'grade_sub1':'A', 'grade_sub2':'B'}]];
let new_arr = [];

new_arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(new_arr); //output : ['students', 'exams', [{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60},{'grade_sub1':'A', 'grade_sub2':'B'}]]

new_arr[2].pop();
let sub_arr = [];
sub_arr = sub_arr.concat(arr);

console.log(sub_arr); //output: ['students', 'exams',[{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to deep clone your array, eg.:

```js
const deepClone = (obj) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));


let arr = ['students', 'exams', [{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60},{'grade_sub1':'A', 'grade_sub2':'B'}]];
let new_arr = [];

new_arr = new_arr.concat(deepClone(arr));
console.log(new_arr); //output : ['students', 'exams', [{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60},{'grade_sub1':'A', 'grade_sub2':'B'}]]

new_arr[2].pop();
let sub_arr = [];
sub_arr = sub_arr.concat(deepClone(arr));

console.log(sub_arr); //output : ['students', 'exams', [{'sub1':80, 'sub2':60},{'grade_sub1':'A', 'grade_sub2':'B'}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could clone a deep copy of an object by using a recursive function as seen below:

```js
const original = [ 'students', 'exams', [
  { 'sub1': 80, 'sub2': 60 },
  { 'grade_sub1': 'A', 'grade_sub2': 'B' }
]];

const clone = val =>
  val == null
    ? null
    : typeof val === 'string'
      ? val
      : Array.isArray(val)
        ? val.map(sub => clone(sub))
        : typeof val === 'object'
          ? Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(val)
            .map(([key, value]) => [key, clone(value)]))
          : val;

const copy = clone(original);

console.log(copy);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```